# Blender 2.8: Best way to copy moves (rotations and translations) between 2 meshes

Tags: mesh, drivers

I have two meshes, « MasterCube » and « TargetCube » in different places. I would like to copy all moves (Translation X/Y/Z and Rotation X/Y/Z) from MasterCube to TargetCube in keeping the original locations of my two meshes. When MasterCube moves, TargetCube have to do the same from his original location.

I tried with « copy rotation », « copy location », « copy transform » and « transformation ». I even tried Hooks and more. I got a partial solution but not complete. For some solution, my TargeCube rotates around the pivot of the MasterCube in place to rotate around its own pivot. For other solution, the TargetCube location move to the MasterCube first off all, and follows this one in a kind of superposed mode.

The only good solution I expect to uses is Drivers. 3 Drivers for each location dimension (x,y,z) using the MasterCube location coordinates in the math expression to compensate, and 3 others for rotation. So, 6 Drivers.

Anyway, for a so simple idea to just clone moves, I guess there is a simplest way to do this. Could you tell me if Drivers really are the regular solution ?

Thank you.

Example of bad result with Parenting. The TargetCube rotates around the MasterCube pivot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what about parenting the target cube to an empty? is it the problem of location that prevent you to do it?

Comment: Parenting is perfect for translations (x,y,z). It's ok too for one rotation axe. But for at least one rotation (ie y) the TargetCube rotate around the MasterCube pivot

Comment: i'm talking about parenting the target cube to an empty, not parenting the target cube to the master cube

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you well, but you suggest to place an "empty master" at the same place of the TargetCube ? If yes, it works, but this is not what I'm looking for. I need to have my two cubes in different places.

Comment: put the empty wherever you want, at the same location as the target cube for example, parent the target cube to the empty, move the empty wherever you want, the cube will follow, and it will act like the master cube except it is not at the same location. But the answer given by Ron Jensen works as well

Comment: other solution: You can also change the Delta Transform Location of the target, in the Properties panel > Object > Transform

Comment: Thank your Moonboots. Change the Delta Transform Location is a good solution to Ron solution because, it fix the problem of the TargetCube location move at the Copy transform setup. Finaly this is equivalent to the expression I add to the drivers. Basically I think the complexity is the same. So, may be the Drivers solution is best. Future experience will tell it....

Answer (score 1):

Is this the effect you're looking for?
[image: Tumbling Animation]

The trick is to set "Mix" to "After Original" and the "Copy Transforms" constraint goes on the follower object.
[image: The Settings]

Comment: Hello Ron. Thank your for your answer. I tried this, it failed and I just undersant whty. In fact your solution works, excepted in one case. When the TargetCube is at the Origine (0,0,0). Because, the TargetCube moves, when you set the "Copy Transform". And when the TargetCube is at the origine, it comes to merge the same location. So, it works under the condtion the TargetCube is not at the origin.

Comment: Anyway, there still is a problem. When I set the Copy Transform, the TargetCube move to a location that is TargetCube.location + MasterCube.location. And this is breaking my previous modelling.

Comment: if the target object is at the center of the scene it will merge to the same location as the master, but why can't you simply move the target cube in the scene to the location it is supposed to be relatively to the master cube?

Comment: This is what I did just now. But when I was looking for a solution, I tried different solution with the TargetCube at the origin. Just to understand. i didn't realize It was a specific bad choice to solve my problem :-)) Leave an example at the origin to test different solutions is a trap ! ;-)